# Dynamic right boundary in Load Runner 11.52

Tags: java, c, loadrunner

I'm using **Load Runner v11.52.**
The right boundary is dynamically changing - I have used `web_reg_save_param` function but *additional value* is passed by the request during this process.

My exact situation is:

## R̲e̲qu̲e̲s̲t̲ S̲t̲r̲i̲n̲g → R̲e̲s̲po̲n̲s̲e̲ S̲t̲r̲i̲n̲g

## `abcd1234*cat` → `abcd123428*cat`

## `abcd2345*dog` → `abcd234532*dog`

Here `1234` and `2345` are the dynamic value that I should capture but when I do so, it is passing `28` and `32` (which are not present in the request) and also dynamic that I have to capture that in another parameter.

The right boundary `cat` and `dog` which is changing dynamically should also be captured.

If anybody needs any more information I'm more than happy to provide.
Can anyone help me on this can anyone suggest a proper function for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the boundaries before and after your complete string?   This would result in a string similar to:

**!leftboundary!abcd1234*cat!rightboundary!**

Capture the entire string set and then take advantage of your foundation skills in C string processing skills to determine the location of the '*' separator, cutting your string into two distinct strings for correlation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve what you're looking for by clicking the "Advanced" button when defining a rule, and specifying the "Length" parameter. This will instruct the rule to correlate just a substring of the what appears between the boundaries

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Better make a use of regular expression.

for example:
If u want to fetch dynamic value - abcd123428*cat

use, web_reg_save_param_regex("Name=cPetId", "LB/dig=abcd([0-9]*)" , "RB=*cat" , LAST);

Answer (score 0):

Loadrunner uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) syntax for regular expression. The output with the below code will be **cat** and **dog** . Use this similarly for other dynamic values.

```
  web_reg_save_param_regexp(
    "ParamName=dynamicAnimal",
    "RegExp=.*\*([a-z]*)",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    LAST);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use lr_save_param_regexp function which allows you to use regular expressions.